# how limit image dragging within the screen?? Expecting suggestions

Tags: android

Is there any way to restric the movement of dragging within the screen ?.If u have suggestions or useful links regarding this,plzz send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can do is you can find the position of your layout on screen on which your view is present which you are dragging.
 like if your view which you are dragging have name `my_view`.

`my_view.getTop();` it will give top position of your view according to its parent.
like that you can find all your position of top, bottom, right, left.

now in you can override the

```
my_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int event_type = event.getAction();
            // Here you can get the current position of your view.
            // check your current positions with parent position and if it is crossing then just set it according to your parent.
            return false;
        }
    });
```

so what you have to do is get your parent position(left, top, bottom, right) and child view position. check child view position in ontouchlistner or in that function where you are setting new positions for dragging.

hope it will help you.